# How to convert a mel spectrogram to log-scaled mel spectrogram

Tags: python, speech-to-text

I was reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.04363.pdf) on environmental noise discrimination using Convolution Neural Networks and wanted to reproduce their results. They convert WAV files into log-scaled mel spectrograms. How do you do this? I am able to convert a WAV file to a mel spectrogram

```
y, sr = librosa.load('audio/100263-2-0-117.wav',duration=3)
ps = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=y, sr=sr)
librosa.display.specshow(ps, y_axis='mel', x_axis='time')
```

[image: mel spectrogram]

I am also able to *display* it as a log scaled spectrogram:

```
librosa.display.specshow(ps, y_axis='log', x_axis='time')
```

[image: log scaled image]

Clearly, they look different, but the actual spectrogram `ps` is the same. Using librosa, **how can I convert this melspectrogram into a log scaled melspectrogram?** Furthermore, what is the use of a log scaled spectrogram over the original? Is it just to reduce the variance of the Frequency domain to make it comparable to the time axis, or something else?

Answer (score 6):

I think you're wrongly interpreting what the authors meant by log-scaled. When the authors mention log-scaled, they are not referring to the frequency (y) axis, although spectrograms are typically log-scaled here. They are instead referring to the scale of the 3rd dimension in the spectrogram. In your case, the raw spectrogram is displaying **power** in color. What you want is instead **decibels**, which *are* log-scaled.

In your case, the code would look like this:

```
y, sr = librosa.load('audio/100263-2-0-117.wav',duration=3)
ps = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=y, sr=sr)
ps_db= librosa.power_to_db(ps, ref=np.max)

lr.display.specshow(ps_db, x_axis='time', y_axis='mel')
```

Note: Each spectrogram will be scaled based off of the ref within librosa.power_to_db. If you do not supply anything, librosa just shoves a 1 in there, which may or may not be what you're looking for. You can also try out np.median.

Comment: Shoul we say: "log-magnitude mel-scale spectrogram".

Answer (score 1):

here is example code to extract audio features as log spectrogram using python scipy:

```
from scipy.io import wavfile
from scipy import signal

sample_rate=16000
window_size=20
step_size=10
eps=1e-10
rate, data = wavfile.read('filename.wav')
if data.ndim > 1 : # ignore  channels 2+
    data = data[:, 0]
nperseg = int(round(window_size * sample_rate / 1e3))
noverlap = int(round(step_size * sample_rate / 1e3))
freqs, times, spec = signal.spectrogram(data,fs=sample_rate,window='hann',nperseg=nperseg,noverlap=noverlap)
log_specgram = np.log(spec.T.astype(np.float32) + eps)
```